# Unexpected end of content while loading JObject

Tags: c#, json, rest, json.net, workfront-api

I have a console application pulling data from Workfront. It's been working for a while, until a couple weeks ago it started throwing errors and aborting the application. 
I have narrowed down the issue and it seems like the problem is being generated when I try to parse out a string into a JToken. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
private JToken ReadResponse(Stream stream) {
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
  string body = reader.ReadToEnd();
  JToken test = JObject.Parse(body);
  return test;
}
```

This is the error I get:
`[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException]  {"Unexpected end of content while loading JObject. Path 'data[3700]', line 1, position 12298025."}  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException`

Any ideas on why is this happening?
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What line does the error happen on

Comment: 12,298,025 bytes is quite long.  Is there any chance the server is truncating its response?

Comment: The problem happens at the `JToken test = JObject.Parse(body);`

Comment: First guess is your json isn't valid, trying capturing the body and run it through a json validator.  I had this same error and my json was missing the final }